# Any documentation on SSDT deployment?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

There is a brand new way of developing with databases with Visual Studio 2012: SQL Server Data Tools.

I am a user of the good old VSDBCMD. I use VSDBCMD on a daily basis to updates databases on staging and production servers. Now I fail to find documentation on how to use SSDT the same way I am using VSDBCMD.

The MSDN page [How to: **Prepare a Database for Deployment From a Command Prompt** by Using VSDBCMD.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193258%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explains how to prepare a production server for deployment with VSDBCMD. There is no equivalent documentation page for this task with SSDT. Does anyone have a valuable documentation about that?

The MSDN page [How to: **Deploy Changes to New or Existing Databases**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833271%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explains how to deploy a database on a production server from compiled files using VSDBCMD. There is no equivalent documentation page for this task with SSDT. Does anyone have a valuable documentation about that?

The whole [Build and Deploy Databases to a Staging or Production Environment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193413%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (VSDBCMD) documentation section exists nowhere in the [SSDT documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272686%28v=vs.103%29.aspx).

It seems like there is no documentation at all concerning this new technology. Or am I not able to use a search engine? I don't know. Can someone enlighten me?

My goal is to deploy SSDT projects on production machines without installing Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run the sqlpqckage.exe on a production server, you will have to install [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?amp;amp;displaylang=en&id=29065#dacframework) The following elements must be installed .

- Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework
- Microsoft® System CLR Types for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012
- Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Transact-SQL ScriptDom

If not installed, you will get an error like

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom, Version=11.0.0.0
```

And here is the [SqlPackage.exe command line reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=VS.103%29.aspx)

[This video](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2012/DBI311) helped me get the info.

Comment: I blogged about this here: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2012/10/ssdt-importing-existing-database.html - could be useful.